# Robot Circuit design

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, battery-charging

I have tried my hand at designing a circuit for a *tiny* robot, but I am not sure at all if it will work. I thought about the robotics stack exchange, but this seems more suited to the job.

**The questions:**

---

**Which parts of the circuits will not work**

---

**Where do the traces/wires need to be thicker for more current**

---

(Sorry about different formats)

**Motor Board**
[image]

**Main Board**
[image: Main Board image]

The image at top is my attempt at designing the motors board for the robot, which also contains the batteries and charger. Assuming the microcontrollers are programmed correctly, which part is a bad fit/ has a wrong value.

To clear this up, I am using 80 mAh micro gearmotors, I think that the LB1836M IC may be too powerful for these tiny motors.

[LB1836M IC](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LB1836M-D.PDF)

[The gearmotor](https://nfpshop.com/product/6mm-mini-dc-gear-motor-15mm-type-model-nfp609-5-14-0675-standard-shaft)

[The battery](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13853)

Description:
The robot's goal is to be a low-cost (on the order of 10-30 USD) swarm robot. The five IR sensors act as proximity sensors / communication

*Edit:* Rephrased some of the question - thanks to Leon Heller

*Edit:* Updated Schematics for human-friendliness

Comment: 1.1 A isn't a potential! Why should it be too high for the motors?

Comment: 'the LB1836M IC may be too powerful for these tiny motors' - it seems like you misunderstand how motors, or motor drivers, work. this motor driver is a fine choice for this application. Other than that, you should ask a more specific question.

Comment: In my experience, when making a schematic using parts I haven't used before: if I have to guess or make assumptions about anything, I usually get it wrong. (Or at least it feels like it!) You just need to read the datasheet for every part, and understand exactly how to interface with each pin. There's no simple shortcut.

Comment: What are Q3-Q7?  Always put component names on schematic.  Use an optocoupler symbol.  Make it if you must.  If you cannot make the symbol with the schematic capture package.  Find a new package.  Q3-Q7 appears to be opto-isolating a U2 input to a U2 output.  Why?  Hard to tell how R5 is connected on motor board.  You are making straight lines to make connections, even if it crosses components.  Surprisingly this makes it hard to follow.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Q3-Q7 Are LTR-301 phototransistors. I also updated the schematics. Hope that helps.